# How to get results from a compute thread to the GUI thread - do I need QSharedMemory?

Tags: c++, qt

I need a sharing interface between two threads (main thread (GUI) and compute thread). During startup the main thread stores all signals in `QHash(<QString Signalname, double value>)`. The second thread writes the key/value every compute step. Should I store them in `QSharedMemory`?

My application has two threads. A GUI thread and Compute thread. The User, through the GUI, can start the simulation in a fast mode or in real time mode. The computations evolve the simulated model through time. They are fast enough that they can be performed faster than real time. If you insert delays, they can be kept down to real-time speed, as you would, e.g. in a game or animation.

The Compute thread should perform the computations in one of the four modes:

1. **Fast** mode: the computations are done without delays and evolve the model faster than real time. This is implemented in Thread run with `while (...) { ... run_ComputeFunction()... }`
2. **Real-Time** mode: This is implemented in Thread run with QTimer Timeout and slot `run_ComputeFunction()`.
3. **Single-Step** mode: The user initiates each time step through the GUI. This is akin to single-stepping in a debugger. This is implemented in Thread run with start Thread than run_ComputeFunction than wait condition.
4. **Stop** mode: The computations are stopped.

Comment: It is complex question. In two words: you need to use write and use your own allocators (for QHash, QString and double), that will work with shared memory buffer. But I suggest you to look at boost interprocess containers.

Comment: It may not be practical in your particular case, but if it is it'd be much easier for you if you can work out an ordering for the signals e.g. if all accessing threads/processes will see the same set of `Signalname` values, they could `std::sort` them and use `std::binary_search` to get an array index - then treat the shared memory as an array of `double`s.

Comment: Is really a SharedMemory needed? SharedMemory is for communication between processes. For communication between threads inside the same process the data can be more easily shared as global variable or on the heap, as long as all accesses are properly synchronized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: You don't.

> I need a sharing interface between two **threads** (main thread (GUI) and compute thread). *(emphasis mine)*

`QSharedMemory` only makes sense for multi*processing*, not multi*threading*. The whole idea of threads is that they are like processes, but share **all** of the memory of the process they are in.

Thus, all of your threads see *all* of the memory available to your process, and you don't need to do anything at all to share it.

You need to figure out whether the compute thread should be:

1. Only updating a data structure shared with the main thread, *or*
2. Notifying the main thread of changes in its state by providing the key-value pair that changed, *or*
3. Both.

The problem with updating a data structure is that unless you *also* provide notification of changes, the main thread will have no choice but poll the structure for changes. So now you're running some code on the main thread that doesn't do much, but runs on a timer and forces CPU wakeups and makes your mobile and virtualized users hate you. Not nice.

Since any access to a shared data structure must be protected by a mutex so that the readers aren't reading gibberish while a writer updates the value, it's up to you to decide between:

1. Keeping only one copy of the data structure in the compute thread, and accessing it under mutex protection. The main and compute threads will compete for that mutex and performance will suffer.
2. Keeping two copies of the data structure - one on the compute thread, and another in any thread that wishes to track the progress of the computation.
3. Keeping one copy of a lock-free data structure.

Below, I demonstrate how to keep a separate data structure in the compute and main threads. I'm also leveraging the Model-View and a standard model to provide the UI for the compute engine.

The implementation of the computer is split between an abstract base class, and the concrete implementation specific to your computational problem. All that a concrete class needs to do is to implement two methods: one to calculate one simulation time step, returning its length, and another to notify its users of changes to the data.

The `Computer` object provides random updates to its data, "simulating" a time step of random duration. It blocks for random amounts of time, by sleeping for 1/4 of the duration of a randomly selected time step. Thus it acts as if it could calculate the data ~4x faster than realtime.

The `AbstractComputer` takes this simple functionality and builds upon it to provide the four modes of operation: single-step, real time and fast.

The amount of computation performed in one chunk by `computeChunk`, in terms of simulated passage of time, is set to `m_notifyPeriod`, here set to 20ms.

In all modes of operation other than `Stop`, at least single chunk is always computed before returning control to the event loop to keep the computational thread responsive. A single timer is used to return control from event loop to the computer and to schedule future computations. In the real time mode, if the computation is ahead from the real time clock, the next computation is scheduled at the appropriate moment in time so that it runs in real time. In the fast mode, the timer is set to zero timeout, immediately returning control from the event loop to perform another computation chunk. This has very low overhead.

The abstract computer keeps track of accumulated simulated time steps (`simTime`).

The computer object runs in its own thread and provides periodic, randomly-generated updates to its data. Changes to data are indicated via a notification signal. The updated data is inserted into the standard model in the UI object. The signal-slot connection linking the two objects is of a queued type - the `newValue` slot invocations happen in the main thread.

The dropdown combo has focus, so all you need to do to single-step is press/hold <kbd>↓</kbd> (down arrow key).

Note that the implementation of `AbstractComputer` is done in such a way as not to block for longer than the larger of `m_notifyPeriod` or one simulation step (one call to `compute`). On a single-core machine, moving the `Computer` instance to another thread will actually decrease performance! The `main` is implemented to take this into account.

Finally, as a performance optimization, you should use [string interning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc8ky.png) in a (optionally sorted) string table and use indexes into this table (a.k.a. atoms) as parameter keys, not raw strings.

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <random>

class AbstractComputer : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY (Mode mode READ mode WRITE setMode NOTIFY modeChanged)
   Q_PROPERTY (double simTime READ simTime WRITE setSimTime
               RESET resetSimTime NOTIFY simTimeChanged)
public:
   enum Mode { Stop, Step, RealTime, Fast };
protected:
   typedef double Time; ///< units of seconds

   /// Performs one computation step and returns the amount of time the simulation has
   /// been advanced by. The computation updates one or more parameters in the map, but
   /// doesn't signal the updates. The changed parameters are kept in set.
   /// This method can change m_mode to Stop to direct the calling code to stop/pause
   /// the simulation.
   virtual Time compute() = 0;

   /// Notifies of accumulated changes and clears the update set.
   virtual void notify() = 0 ;
private:
   Mode m_mode, m_prevMode;
   QBasicTimer m_timer;
   QElapsedTimer m_timeBase;
   qint64 m_lastNotification; ///< Last m_timeBase at which notification was issued.
   Time m_notifyPeriod; ///< Real time period to issue data change notifications at.
   Time m_modeSimTime;  ///< Simulation time accumulated in current mode.
   Time m_simTime;      ///< Total simulation time.

   /// Computes a chunk of work that amounts to m_notifyPeriod in simulated time
   void computeChunk() {
      Time t = 0;
      do
         t += compute();
      while (m_mode != Stop && t < m_notifyPeriod);
      m_modeSimTime += t;
      m_simTime += t;
   }

   /// Runs computations according to the selected mode. In RealTime and Fast modes,
   /// the notifications are issued at least every m_notifyPeriod.
   void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
      if (ev->timerId() != m_timer.timerId()) return;
      const Time startSimTime = m_simTime;
      const Mode startMode = m_mode;
      switch (m_mode) {
      case Step:
         m_simTime += compute();
         m_timer.stop();
         m_mode = Stop;
         break;
      case Stop:
         m_timer.stop();
         break;
      case RealTime:
         if (m_prevMode != RealTime) {
            m_modeSimTime = 0.0;
            m_timeBase.start();
         }
         computeChunk();
         if (m_mode == RealTime) {
            int ahead = round(m_modeSimTime * 1000.0 - m_timeBase.elapsed());
            if (ahead < 0) ahead = 0;
            m_timer.start(ahead, Qt::PreciseTimer, this);
         }
         break;
      case Fast:
         if (m_prevMode != Fast) {
            m_timeBase.start();
            m_lastNotification = 0;
         }
         do
            computeChunk();
         while (m_mode == Fast
                && ((m_timeBase.elapsed() - m_lastNotification) < m_notifyPeriod*1000.0));
         m_lastNotification = m_timeBase.elapsed();
         break;
      }
      notify();
      if (startSimTime != m_simTime) emit simTimeChanged(m_simTime);
      if (m_prevMode != m_mode || startMode != m_mode) emit modeChanged(m_mode);
      m_prevMode = m_mode;
   }
public:
   AbstractComputer(QObject * parent = 0) :
      QObject(parent), m_mode(Stop), m_prevMode(Stop), m_notifyPeriod(0.02) /* 50 Hz */,
      m_simTime(0.0)
   {}
   Q_SIGNAL void modeChanged(AbstractComputer::Mode mode); // fully qualified type is required by moc
   Q_SIGNAL void simTimeChanged(double);
   Q_SLOT void setMode(AbstractComputer::Mode mode) { // fully qualified type is required by moc
      if (m_mode == mode) return;
      m_mode = mode;
      if (m_mode != Stop) m_timer.start(0, this); else m_timer.stop();
   }
   Q_SLOT void stop() { setMode(Stop); }
   Mode mode() const { return m_mode; }
   double simTime() const { return m_simTime; }
   void setSimTime(double t) { if (m_simTime != t) { m_simTime = t; emit simTimeChanged(t); } }
   void resetSimTime() { setSimTime(0.0); }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AbstractComputer::Mode)

class Computer : public AbstractComputer {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   typedef QHash<QString, double> Map;
private:
   typedef QSet<QString> Set;
   std::default_random_engine m_eng;
   Map m_data;
   Set m_updates;

   Time compute() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      // Update one randomly selected parameter.
      auto n = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, m_data.size()-1)(m_eng);
      auto it = m_data.begin();
      std::advance(it, n);
      auto val = std::normal_distribution<double>()(m_eng);
      *it = val;
      m_updates.insert(it.key());
      float tau = std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(0.001, 0.1)(m_eng);
      // Pretend that we run ~4x faster than real time
      QThread::usleep(tau*1E6/4.0);
      return tau;
   }
   void notify() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      for (auto param : m_updates)
         emit valueChanged(param, m_data[param]);
      m_updates.clear();
   }
public:
   Computer(const Map & data, QObject * parent = 0) :
      AbstractComputer(parent), m_data(data) {}
   Map data() const { return m_data; }
   Q_SIGNAL void valueChanged(const QString & key, double val);
};

class UI : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QHash<QString, int> m_row;
   QStandardItemModel m_model;
   QFormLayout m_layout { this };
   QTableView m_view;
   QComboBox m_mode;
public:
   UI(const Computer * computer, QWidget * parent = 0) :
      QWidget(parent),
      m_model(computer->data().size() + 1, 2, this)
   {
      auto data = computer->data();
      m_mode.addItem("Stop", Computer::Stop);
      m_mode.addItem("Step", Computer::Step);
      m_mode.addItem("Real Time", Computer::RealTime);
      m_mode.addItem("Fast", Computer::Fast);
      m_mode.setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
      m_view.setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
      m_layout.addRow(&m_view);
      m_layout.addRow("Sim Mode", &m_mode);
      m_model.setItem(0, 0, new QStandardItem("Sim Time [s]"));
      m_model.setItem(0, 1, new QStandardItem);
      int row = 1;
      for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
         m_model.setItem(row, 0, new QStandardItem(it.key()));
         m_model.setItem(row, 1, new QStandardItem(QString::number(it.value())));
         m_row[it.key()] = row++;
      }
      newMode(computer->mode());
      newSimTime(computer->simTime());
      m_view.setModel(&m_model);
      connect(&m_mode, static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
              [this](int i){
         emit modeChanged((AbstractComputer::Mode)m_mode.itemData(i).toInt());
      });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void modeChanged(AbstractComputer::Mode);
   Q_SLOT void newValue(const QString & key, double val) {
      m_model.item(m_row[key], 1)->setText(QString::number(val));
   }
   Q_SLOT void newSimTime(double t) {
      m_model.item(0, 1)->setText(QString::number(t));
   }
   Q_SLOT void newMode(AbstractComputer::Mode mode) {
      m_mode.setCurrentIndex(m_mode.findData(mode));
   }
};

struct Thread : public QThread { ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); } };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   qRegisterMetaType<AbstractComputer::Mode>();
   Computer::Map init;
   init.insert("Foo", 1);
   init.insert("Bar", 2);
   init.insert("Baz", 3);
   Computer computer(init);
   QScopedPointer<Thread> thread;
   UI ui(&computer);
   QObject::connect(&computer, &Computer::valueChanged, &ui, &UI::newValue);
   QObject::connect(&computer, &Computer::simTimeChanged, &ui, &UI::newSimTime);
   QObject::connect(&computer, &Computer::modeChanged, &ui, &UI::newMode);
   QObject::connect(&ui, &UI::modeChanged, &computer, &Computer::setMode);
   int threadCount = Thread::idealThreadCount();
   if (threadCount == -1 || threadCount > 1) { // Assume a multicore machine
      thread.reset(new Thread);
      computer.moveToThread(thread.data());
      thread->start();
      // Prevent the bogus "QBasicTimer::stop: Failed." warnings.
      QObject::connect(thread.data(), &QThread::finished, &computer, &Computer::stop);
   }
   ui.show();
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

My "random words" dictionary *does* consist of three items, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you haven't come across it yet, Qt provides a QSharedMemory example that should get you started in the right direction: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-sharedmemory-example.html

The QThread documention will also help: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

If you're still stuck, you can always update your question with a minimal code example.